# onSensorChanged() not fired on Android (nVidia Shield Tablet)

Tags: android, nvidia, android-sensors

I'm trying to create an augmented reality app for the nVidia shield.
I tried my app on another Android device and it works.
Unfortunately, on the shield, the onSensorChanged event is not fired.

Here's my code:

```
        _sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener()
        {
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                AndroidAttitude.this.processSensorEvent(event);
            }

            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy)
            {
            }
        };

        Thread sensorThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();

                _sensorLooper = Looper.myLooper();
                Handler handler = new Handler();

                _sensorManager = (SensorManager)_context.getSystemService("sensor");

                Sensor sensor = _sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
                _sensorManager.registerListener(_sensorEventListener, sensor, 0, _sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

                Looper.loop();
            }
        });

        sensorThread.start();
```

And this is where I transform my values into a rotation matrix:

```
private synchronized void processSensorEvent(SensorEvent event)
{
    float[] rotationVector = { -event.values[1], event.values[0], event.values[2] };

    float[] quaternion = new float[4];
    float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];

    _sensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector(quaternion, rotationVector);
    _sensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, rotationVector);

}
```

Any idea why it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. I just found out where the problem was coming from.
The magnetic cover of my tablet was messing with the magnetometer, resulting in the Game Rotation Vector sensor and the magnetic field sensor not sending data.
I can't believe I spent hours scratching my head to fix this problem...

Answer (score 1):

Ok if you have to use `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`, the change from `SENSOR_DELAY_GAME` to `SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL`

```
  Sensor sensor = _sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
        _sensorManager.registerListener(_sensorEventListener, sensor, 0, _sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
```

Comment: Thank you, but what I'm trying to do is to get the rotation matrix so using TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR allows me to get values directly (I've updated my post)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST?

Answer (score 0):

Since `registerListener` does not throw exception if you pass in a null `sensor`, you should check `sensor`for `null`. It looks like your device does not have `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`

Comment: The device has the sensor, it is detected in various other apps and registerListener doesn't return null.
This morning, while trying again on my tablet, the sensor sent data. It's now working and I have no idea why... probably an Android update during the night?